# How can I be notified when a session expires?

Tags: session, spark-java

I've had a look through the documentation on sessions: http://sparkjava.com/documentation#sessions and I am stuck.

Is there any way for me to act upon a session being closed, in both cases where a session is terminated manually via `req.session(false).invalidate()` or the session times-out.

The reason I'm asking for this functionality is for cases where you might store a Closeable object on a session as an attribute, which when the session timesout, I would like to call `session().getAttribute("MyCloseableResource").close();`

I have not really tried anything other than reading the docs - or the javadoc on `req.session()`. I have no idea what else to look for.